# Binding Data from the Database to a Dropdown List in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, oracle

I am following a 3 Tier Architecture so I don't want to attach the data source in the aspx page like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ToolTip="Select User" ID="users" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CURRENCY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION" 
     DataValueField="CURRENCY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION" Width="100px">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
     ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT &quot;Usernames&quot; FROM &quot;Users&quot;">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to have a method in the datalayer which calls the same SQL Statement and receives back data, then I would have a method in the business layer which binds the data to the drop down list like this one:

```
private void populateUnitList()
{
    unitList.DataSource = DatabaseHandler.getUnitList();
    unitList.DataBind();
}
```

This is the code I have in the Database Handler:

```
public static string getUnitList()
{
    DatabaseAdapter dba = DatabaseAdapter.getInstance();
    string sqlQuery = ("SELECT DISTINCT Usernames FROM Users");
    return dba.queryDatabase(sqlQuery).ToString();
}
```

I am using C#, and .NET Framework 4.0. This is not working for me yet.

---

Update #3:

It is working as I want it too, here it goes:

```
//controller class
private void populateCurrencyList()
{
    currencyList.DataSource = DatabaseHandler.getCurrencyList();
    currencyList.DataTextField = "CURRENCY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION";
    currencyList.DataValueField = "CURRENCY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION";
    currencyList.DataBind();
}

//db handler class
public static DataTable getCurrencyList()
{
    DatabaseAdapter dba = DatabaseAdapter.getInstance();
    string sqlQuery = ("SELECT DISTINCT CURRENCY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION FROM CURRENCY");

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dba.queryDatabase(sqlQuery));
    return dt;
}

//controller class, the !IsPostBack prevents duplication of fields
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        populateUnitList();
        populateCurrencyList();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is unitList's DataSource.  You're returning a string.

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed any suggestions of how I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SqlConnection  conn = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring")
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ();

cmd.CommandText = " Select * From GetUsersID";
cmd.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
DataTable dt  = new DataTable();

dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
conn.Close();

DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
DropDownList1.DataBind(); `
```

You have to mention the DataTextField  and DataValueField  property of the drop down list. DataTextField  is the field to display and DataValueField is the value of that field

Comment: I tried a very similar approach to yours, but it's not working, check my original post where there is update for more info

Answer (score 2):

A DataSource must implement IEnumerable but your database handler methods returns a string. I don't know what your databaseAdapter class is doing but it should expose an enumerable collection of rows from the database and this is what you need to return.

Comment: So you would put them in a vector or something, and then bind that?

Comment: A Generic List or an Observable Collection.  This wouldn't be a good place for a vector.  Since vectors haven't been in .NET since 2.0

Comment: I would imagine that the return type of dba.queryDatabase(sqlQuery) is probably a collection of some sort. You should be able to get rid of the 'ToString()' and bind this as well. Note that you'll also need to specify the Text and Value fields (see response from waqar) in order to ensure the correct data items are bound and displayed.

Comment: @Dan Andrews - Look at my original post to see my updated version, still not working, I am using a DataTable as recommended

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" DataTextField="Desc" DataValueField="Id"
runat="server" />


List<yourclass> operation = new List<yourclass>();
ddl1.DataSource = GetOperationData; //get connect to your BAL or DAL
ddl1.DataTextField = "Desc";
ddl1.DataValueField = "Id";
ddl1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an Objectdatasource in your aspx page rather than a Sqldatasource

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx